# Thread.Sleep() doesn't work in application Console C#

Tags: c#, timeout, console-application

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string PATH = @"C:\My_PATH\";
        const string FILE_NAME = "data_acquistion2";
        const string DATETIME_STOP_RECORD = "01-04-15 17:18";
        bool fichierNonExistant = false;
        PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
        PerformanceCounter ramCounter;` 

        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
        cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

        ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

        string actualPeriod = "";
        if (!File.Exists(PATH + FILE_NAME + ".csv"))
        {
            FileStream myFs = File.Create(PATH + FILE_NAME + ".csv");
            fichierNonExistant = true;
            myFs.Close();

        }

        StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(PATH + FILE_NAME + ".csv", true);
        if (fichierNonExistant == true)
        {
            myWriter.WriteLine("CPU Used (%)" + "," + "RAM Free (%)" + "," + "Hour and record Date");
        }

        while (actualPeriod != DATETIME_STOP_RECORD)
        {
            actualPeriod = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
           // Console.WriteLine(periodeActuelle);
            myWriter.WriteLine(cpuCounter.NextValue() + "," + ramCounter.NextValue() + "," + actualPeriod);
           Thread.Sleep(20000); //If I add this the program doesn't write in the csv file
        }

    }


}`
```

Hi,

I have a problem with Thread.Sleep in C#, I developped a code for writting the % CPU (used) and the RAM directly into a csv file.

It works without a delaying, but I want to write this values every 20s, that's why I need to use Thread.Sleep(20000).
I have also tried Task.Delay and I have the same problem.

Comment: what does "doesn't work" and "Problem just right here" *mean*? what *happens*? And what did you *expect* to happen?

Comment: unrelated, but I would find it very unlikely that it ever *exits*, due to the `!=` comparing strings; IMO you should keep `actualPeriod` as a `DateTime` and use `<`

Comment: `DATETIME_STOP_RECORD` does not include seconds, but `actualPeriod` does.  So this is going to loop forever.  Also depending on your current culture there might also be a discrepency between `-` and `/`.  The best bet is to listen to Marc and just compare `DateTime`s.

Comment: I have add some changes you can read it Marc Gravell. The problem is if I add the Thread.Sleep() the program write anything in the csv file.

Comment: Marc Gravell is right.. comparing `"dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"` with `"01-04-15 17:18"` will catch you in an infinite loop...

Comment: Yes the condition in my loop works.

Comment: @Ironboy07 that sounds simply like a flushing problem... have you tried using `File.AppendText` rather than keeping a writer open?

Comment: @Ironboy07 no, your loop condition does not work; you are mistaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the Thread.Sleep( ). You're using a StreamWriter and since your program is probably never closing, you need to flush the StreamWriter after you write.

Add

myWriter.Flush( ) before the Thread.Sleep( )

Comment: You're welcome.  Check your while loop, as others have mentioned, it looks like it's infinite and kindly check my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is if I add the Thread.Sleep() the program write anything in the csv file.

(I'm assuming there is a missing "doesn't" in there)

This sounds like a flushing problem; your changes are still buffered in the writer. You could *try* using `myWriter.Flush();`, but note that you might still get problems with shared file access etc. Since you're going to be pausing for 20 seconds (a very long time to a computer), you might as well keep the file closed when you aren't using it. It would be more effective to get rid of the writer *completely* and simply use `File.AppendText(path, newLine)` as necessary, noting to include your choice of line-ending in the string. Then the file will be closed almost all of the time.

Additionally: your loop exit condition needs attention; right now it will *never* exit of its own choice (since `actualPeriod` includes seconds, and `DATETIME_STOP_RECORD` does not). It would be better to use a `DateTime` and `<`, too (you could go from before the time to after the time without ever hitting exactly the time).

Comment: Perfect it works ! Thanks for the explanation. Ok I will change my loop also. I understand now how it works